# Compare results of two selects statements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

How can i compare the results of two select statements in TSQL (2014)?

my both queries:

```
SELECT CallDisposition, count(CallDisposition) as Count
  FROM [bs_Reporting].[dbo].[Termination_Call_Detail]
  where (DateTime between dateadd(minute,@timespan,convert(datetime2,(GETDATE())+ @count)) AND convert(datetime2,(GETDATE())+ @count))
  Group by CallDisposition
```

```
SELECT CallDisposition, count(CallDisposition) as Count
  FROM [bs_Reporting].[dbo].[Termination_Call_Detail]
  where DateTime >= dateadd(minute,@timespan,convert(datetime2,(GETDATE())))
  Group by CallDisposition
```

Results of Query 1:

```
+-----------------+-------+
| CallDisposition | Count |
+-----------------+-------+
|               2 |     2 |
|               3 |     8 |
|               4 |     8 |
|               7 |    21 |
|              10 |    16 |
|              13 |   738 |
|              14 |    45 |
|              15 |    14 |
|              19 |     8 |
|              28 |    41 |
|              29 |    12 |
|              52 |    76 |
|              55 |    1  |
+-----------------+-------+
```

Results of Query 2:

```
+-----------------+-------+
| CallDisposition | Count |
+-----------------+-------+
|               2 |     4 |
|               3 |     7 |
|               4 |     6 |
|               6 |     2 |
|               7 |    22 |
|              10 |     6 |
|              13 |   703 |
|              14 |    67 |
|              15 |    11 |
|              19 |     4 |
|              26 |     1 |
|              28 |    62 |
|              29 |    10 |
|              52 |    79 |
+-----------------+-------+
```

The main problem behind, the results of both queries can be different.
Based on example above: CallDisposition 6 and 26 are missing in Query 1.
CallDispoition 55 is missing in Query 2
Note: CallDispoition values 0-100 can be expected, maybe that helps?!

The expected result should look like that:

```
+-----------------+-------+
| CallDisposition | Count |
+-----------------+-------+
| 2               |     2 |
| 3               |     1 |
| 4               |     2 |
| 6               |     2 |
| 7               |     1 |
| 10              |    10 |
| ..              |       |
| ..              |       |
| ..              |       |
| 52              |     3 |
| 55              |     1 |
+-----------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH S1 AS (SELECT CallDisposition, count(CallDisposition) as Count
  FROM [bs_Reporting].[dbo].[Termination_Call_Detail]
  where (DateTime between dateadd(minute,@timespan,convert(datetime2,(GETDATE())+ @count)) AND convert(datetime2,(GETDATE())+ @count))
  Group by CallDisposition
)
,S2 AS (
SELECT CallDisposition, count(CallDisposition) as Count
  FROM [bs_Reporting].[dbo].[Termination_Call_Detail]
  where DateTime >= dateadd(minute,@timespan,convert(datetime2,(GETDATE())))
  Group by CallDisposition
)
Select ISNULL(S1.CallDisposition,S2.CallDisposition) AS CallDisposition
      ,ABS(ISNULL(S1.COUNT,0)-ISNULL(S2.Count,0)) Count
FROM S1 FULL JOIN S2
      ON S1.CallDisposition=s2.CallDisposition
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I didn't run this code, but it appears that it will produce the result that the original poster is looking for. "Code-only answers", though, don't have a lot of long term value. You should consider editing your post to include some explanation of what your code does, and how it solves the problem. That will help both the OP and anyone else who comes across this post in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I'm puzzled by your expected result and that compares the results. So my solution won't produce such a result. But maybe it helps by pointing you tte right direction.

You can to full join the results on `calldisposition`. That way coexisting `calldisposition` will be put next to each other. If for a `calldisposition` in one result no one exists in the other the columns of the other will be all `NULL`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM (SELECT calldisposition,
                    count(CallDisposition) count
                    FROM [bs_Reporting].[dbo].[Termination_Call_Detail]
                    WHERE (datetime BETWEEN dateadd(minute, @timespan, convert(datetime2, (getdate()) + @count))
                                            AND convert(datetime2, (getdate()) + @count))
                    GROUP BY calldisposition) x
            FULL JOIN (SELECT calldisposition,
                              count(calldisposition) count
                              FROM [bs_Reporting].[dbo].[Termination_Call_Detail]
                              WHERE datetime >= dateadd(minute, @timespan, convert(datetime2, (getdate())))
                       GROUP BY calldisposition) y
                      ON y.calldisposition = x.calldisposition;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably insert the results into a temporary table, then query that. Use a table variable:

```
DECLARE @Results TABLE ([Source] VARCHAR(10), CallDisposition INT, [CallCount] INT)
```

(Use *CallCount* as that's not a reserved word)

```
INSERT INTO @Results(CallDisposition , CallCount, [Source])
SELECT CallDisposition, count(CallDisposition) as Count, [Source] = 'Query1',
  FROM [bs_Reporting].[dbo].[Termination_Call_Detail]
  where (DateTime between dateadd(minute,@timespan,convert(datetime2,(GETDATE())+ @count)) AND convert(datetime2,(GETDATE())+ @count))
  Group by CallDisposition
```

Repeat with your 2nd query, Setting *Source* = 'Query2' (or union with it in the above insert).

Now you can examine your @Results:

```
SELECT r1.* FROM @Results r1 
WHERE [Source] = 'Query1'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X' FROM @Results r2 WHERE [Source] = 'Query2' AND r2.CallDisposition = r1.CallDisposition)
```

(example only; possibly not the most insightful)

Please forgive any slight syntax errors; I don't have SQL Server in front of me.